# Sqaure OAuth Scope Error

Tags: square-connect

Trying to generate an access token using the Square OAuth API and receiving the following error:

> "Some of these scopes are not available for non-multiunit-aware
>   applications."

The scopes requested are:

```
PAYMENTS_READ 
SETTLEMENTS_READ 
ITEMS_READ 
ORDERS_READ 
BANK_ACCOUNTS_READ 
EMPLOYEES_READ 
TIMECARDS_READ 
MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation or returned response indicating which scopes are invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this gap in the documentation. The OAuth scopes `EMPLOYEES_READ`, `EMPLOYEES_WRITE`, `TIMECARDS_READ`, and `TIMECARDS_WRITE` require that an application have access to a merchant's **business entity**, which Connect API applications currently don't by default.

See [Structure of a Square business](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/square-business-structure/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I have submitted a request to have business entity access added to our application.